# Apple Mach-O Linker Error after installing smart,fhir frameworks in Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, swift

After installing the Cocoapods files, this linker  error occured:

> ld: malformed 32-bit x.y.z version number: 0.5.0.5149
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that's a problem with CocoaPods `0.38.1`, try updating to at least `0.38.2` (latest as of writing).